# Delete cache Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, browser-cache

I have a WordPress website, I work to it on local (some CSS fix), but when I deploy it to real server, changes aren't display. If I visit website in private navigation, no problem. But without private mode, the old css is called.

How can I force to refresh the cache browser for user and use the news css file ? 
I try WP Fastest Cache and some other, but they don't work.

(Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it to rename the css file in function.php

Answer (score 1):

we have 3 type of cache:

1. browser cache
2. server cache
3. site cache

cache plugins can clear server and site cache but they can't clear browser cache directly.
only browser can manage browser cache.

the only way to clear browser cache for all users is versioning or renaming the static files that browsers cache them before.

take a look at [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) documents . they have a version parameter. you can change the version each time you did a change to the file and browsers will get the new version for all users.

Answer (score 0):

WP Fastest Cache plugin dashboard navigation menu option WPFC  delete cache and Ctrl+F5 [Screenshot dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCszk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need add version for file like

```
filename.css?v=12
filename.js?v=12
```

or generate version from php

```
$ver = microtime(1);
wp_enqueue_style('stylename', asset_path('styles/style.css'), false, $ver);
wp_enqueue_script('scriptname', asset_path('scripts/main.js'), ['jquery'], $ver, true);
```